# How to I remove space around a series in a chart?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, charts

When I am adding multiple series to a stacked column graph I am getting a space imbetween different series as well as above the series, how can I remove this space?. I am using a dattime format, and it is consistently a gap of one hour either side of the series on the bottom as shown in the picture (the red series shown stack on top of and next to the yellow series
Here is my code for the chart so far (I know that the time difference is wrong in the image):[image]

```
        if (textBoxTotalTime.Text != "")
        {
            string format = "HH:mm";
            totaltime = DateTime.ParseExact(comboBoxFinish.Text, format, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            chartTimespan.Series.Add(textBoxName.Text);

            //This reduces the gap between bars
            chartTimespan.Series[textBoxName.Text]["PointWidth"] = "1";

            chartTimespan.Series[textBoxName.Text].BorderWidth = 0;


            while(starttime<=endtime)
            {                
            chartTimespan.Series[textBoxName.Text].Points.AddXY(starttime, 6);
            starttime = starttime.AddMinutes(15);
            }

            chartTimespan.BackColor = Color.White;
            chartTimespan.Legends.Add(textBoxName.Text);
            chartTimespan.Series[textBoxName.Text].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.StackedColumn;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DataPoints` are meant to be 'stacked'. For this they must be tuples with the **exact same** x-values among the `Series`:

```
    S1.Points.AddXY(1, 10);
    S1.Points.AddXY(2, 20);
    S1.Points.AddXY(3, 30);

    S2.Points.AddXY(1, 10);
    S2.Points.AddXY(2, 30);
    S2.Points.AddXY(3, 10);
```

This results in:

[image: stacked column chart]

Make sure your `DateTime` x-values don't have small differences!

Comment: Cheers, your original response made sense, I was stacking a series on top of each other rather than points, cheers!

Comment: Well, the Series are stacked, but 'pointwise', so they need to have the same x-values..